# jquery code not working in site

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's happening is that my code is working on local server, but it's not working in my site here http://lucrebem.com.br/blog/emponline/47-ganhe-dinheiro-atraves-de-downloads, in the site the code is configured to display a banner ad after the 5 first words of the post, but it's not displaying. I have jquery settle, loaded and working on the site with all the other dependent scripts, and no jquery conflicts at all, but this particular script isn't working.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ku6L240c

The HTML:

```
<div style="width:450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" class="newsitem_text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque urna eu pulvinar maximus. Sed elit nunc, vestibulum ut eros vitae, pellentesque rhoncus ipsum. In et metus non diam porttitor maximus iaculis nec lectus. Quisque sodales scelerisque auctor. Nam rutrum venenatis eros, eu condimentum erat placerat ut. Pellentesque sed tempus sem, eu viverra ipsum. Vestibulum nec turpis convallis, dapibus massa vitae, posuere mauris. Suspendisse mattis tincidunt lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam at tincidunt erat, maximus laoreet ipsum.

    Quisque nunc neque, semper tincidunt placerat eget, blandit a ante. Suspendisse pulvinar, velit eu ultrices pulvinar, lacus sapien tincidunt ipsum, eget sollicitudin mauris eros molestie ex. Etiam quis orci dui. Phasellus vestibulum mollis molestie. Nam condimentum ornare nisl, sed finibus risus tempus vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

    Vestibulum eget ullamcorper lorem. Aliquam mollis elit in sem dapibus dapibus. Proin vel massa a arcu dictum tincidunt in ut ante. Sed feugiat tempus dictum. Praesent in leo ullamcorper, sodales turpis et, vehicula tellus. Duis pellentesque dui ac turpis tristique imperdiet. Sed sed orci lectus.

    Suspendisse non egestas sem, sed tincidunt sem. Etiam laoreet dui sem. Mauris hendrerit massa tempus, euismod arcu sit amet, eleifend quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus id fringilla mauris. Cras dapibus non lacus at finibus. Nullam vitae sagittis neque. Mauris libero velit, interdum non vehicula non, lacinia non augue. Maecenas elementum lacinia interdum.

    Morbi eget mollis nisl. Integer accumsan condimentum tellus, lacinia pellentesque urna volutpat a. Nullam semper sem et erat commodo sollicitudin. Proin rhoncus felis eu aliquam venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla pretium velit eu molestie condimentum. Vestibulum vitae velit mi. Integer nec leo quam. Nam pulvinar ligula congue consectetur tristique. Donec placerat faucibus diam sit amet fermentum. Ut id pellentesque risus. Nunc lacus orci, rhoncus ut risus sed, mattis posuere tellus. Nulla pellentesque eros sed neque consectetur dictum.</div>
```

The javascript:

```js
var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").html().split(' ');
var newHtml = '';

$.each(wordList, function(index, word) {
  newHtml += ' ' + word;
  if (index == 50) {
    newHtml += '<img width="300px" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ee/db/75/eedb7503296066298474bd535b4597cc.gif" />'
  }
});

$(".newsitem_text").html(newHtml);
```

Comment: The issue is not with your above code. There are two other errors appearing in console. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL & Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null

Comment: Handle these first, will fix your issue as per the fiddle.

Comment: You've got a lot of errors in console. Maybe, that's a problem.

Comment: The text in the code above is only an example, but it uses the same class that the article's text uses `newsitem_text`, so it should work on the website too. The javascript is the same code.

Comment: The class is used by the javascript, to replace the part where the banner should be.

Comment: It looks like the code isn't find the class, the class is there, but it's like it doesn't exist.